# How to set max byte length of datagridview when paste

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0, paste, maxlength

I have a datagridview where ***DataNames*** can be entered in a textbox column.I restrict the input length of this column to 6 characters by using the `MaxInputLength` property of the `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`.
Here, I want to explain my problem step by step.
**1**. I wrote Double Byte Characters(eg.１２３４５６７８９０) on a notepad and copy it.Then I went to this `DataGridViewTextBox` ,Right Click and then choosed `Paste`.The `DataGridViewTextBox` showed １２３４５６.
**2**.I wrote Double Byte Characters(eg.１２３４５６) on a notepad and copy it.Then I went to this `DataGridViewTextBox` ,Right Click and then choosed `Paste`.The `DataGridViewTextBox` showed １２３４５６.
So,`MaxInputLength` property only restrict to the input character length( ***not caring single byte or double byte***).
 I want to show only １２３(6 bytes).
Is there a property or a way to restrict the byte character length especially in Paste operation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you don't want a MaxInputLength of 6, but only allow 6 bytes of data in the textbox?

Comment: yes, I want to restrict max input byte length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could just handle it in the TextChangedEvent

Something like:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);
    var textByteCount = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(textBox1.Text);
    var textCharCount = Encoding.UTF8.GetCharCount(textBytes);

    if (textCharCount != textByteCount && textByteCount >= 12)
    {
        textBox1.Text = Encoding.UTF32.GetString(Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(textBox1.Text), 0, 12);
    }
    else if (textBox1.Text.Length >= 6)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, 6);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is an answer -> **'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Comment: you will need to add using `System.Linq;`, I updated the answer to return 6 bytes if its double char or single char,

Comment: Thank you, but My Solution has to base on .net 2.0.So,I can't use System.Linq