# How to limit textbox maxlength by byte in winrt?

Tags: c#, sql, unicode, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

For TextBox, has a attribute "**MaxLength**",but it count all ascii and unicode as 1 character。
But in database, we set the field **varchar(n)** . It treats the ascii 1 and the unicode 2。

How can I limit the textbox input by the byte?

Because no notify before text changed, workaround like this.

```
public class TextBoxEx : TextBox
    {
    private bool bIsChanging;

    public TextBoxEx()
    {
        TextChanged += TextBoxEx_TextChanged;
    }

    public int MaxByteLength { private get; set; }

    private void TextBoxEx_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (bIsChanging || MaxByteLength == 0 || Text.Length*2 <= MaxByteLength)
            return;
        bIsChanging = true;
        int start = SelectionStart;
        Text = TruncateString(Text, MaxByteLength);
        SetLimit();
        SelectionStart = start;
        bIsChanging = false;
    }

    private void SetLimit()
    {
        MaxLength = MaxByteLength - Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Text).Length + Text.Length;
    }

    private static string TruncateString(string text, int max)
    {
        if (max == 0) return text;
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        if (bytes.Length <= max) return text;
        char[] c = text.ToCharArray();
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        int count = 0;
        foreach (char t in c)
        {
            count += Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(t.ToString());
            if (max >= count)
            {
                sb.Append(t);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: A TextBox's internal buffer is in 16-bit code units, so 'ascii' characters still take up 2 bytes as far as the TextBox is concerned, so even if you could tell the TextBox to count bytes instead this wouldn't do what you want. You'll have to write code that looks at the data the TextBox has and computes how many bytes the database would use to store that data. Also, are you sure the database uses just one or two bytes for all characters? If the database is storing the data as UTF-8 then Unicode characters can be one, two, three, or four bytes.

Answer (score 0):

ascii code is hexadecimal as well, which means one character stands for 2 bytes of information

EX: "A" is 41(Hx) 0100 0001 which is 2 bytes and so on

Answer (score 0):

I think you should refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888488/how-to-set-max-byte-length-of-datagridview-when-paste)

It suggests to handle this your self (In this case, it limits 12 bytes length):

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);
    var textByteCount = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(textBox1.Text);
    var textCharCount = Encoding.UTF8.GetCharCount(textBytes);

    if (textCharCount != textByteCount && textByteCount >= 12)
    {
        textBox1.Text = Encoding.UTF32.GetString(Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(textBox1.Text), 0, 12);
    }
    else if (textBox1.Text.Length >= 6)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, 6);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd refrain from using substrings and revert to previous value instead. To allow pasting of longer strings or using the on-screen keyboard that allows to insert entire words - I would save both previous `Text` and previous `SelectionStart`+`SelectionLength` to determine what to clip when text changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply use `MaxLength` of half the `n` in `varchar(n)`.